# Counting formula values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count formula values. If the formula passes back a blank, it should not count it, if the formula passes back a value, count it. How can this be done?

Cell N8 contains `=SUM(5,2)`

Cell N9 contains `2`

Cell N10 contains `=""`

Cell N11 contains `=SUM(9,9)`

My formula to count the cells that gives a value of 4: `=COUNTIF(N8:N11,"<>"&"")`

The value given should be 3, as N10 contains a passed back formula of nothing, however, it's counting as it is a formula. I understand you can use a wild card like `?*` to not count formulas, but then it would defeat my purpose. How could I go about this?

Comment: Use `COUNTA(N8:N11)` instead. [See here for more info on this formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509)  Note that this won't work if your `N10` is truly a formula that has `=""` in it. If the value of `N10` is completely empty, then it will work fine.

Comment: @JNevill the formula within N8-N11 will pass back either a number or a empty string like `=""`.

Comment: Perhaps then: `=COUNTA(N8:N11) - COUNTIF(N8:N11,"")` This will count any populated cell (including formulas that return nothing) and subtract any empty cells (where the formula returns nothing).

Comment: And it's curious that your original attempt `COUNTIF(N8:N11,"<>""""")` doesn't work since my previous comment just tests the opposite of that in order to subtract.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using SUMPRODUCT. You cannot use <>"" because "" does not have a numerical value for another value to be less than, or greater than.

Since we can however test for ""="" then we return true, for a value of 1. Then we just need the inverse of those values in an array, so 1- gets us there, and SUMPRODUCT does the rest.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1-(N8:N11=""))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer for a workaround to `=""` not being blank. Why the `1-..` though?

Comment: Because we want the blanks to be zeros, and the 'not blank's to be 1. This statement returns true for blanks, (which equates to 1), and false for 'not blank's (which equates to 0) so 1- will give us the opposite of each value for the array.